# Post received through axios in react is undefined in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, axios

I am sending user login info with axios in react to the nodejs server. However, my data in nodejs is undefined.

Here is my react js code: -

```
const reqData = { user: loginID, password }
const loginResult = await axios.post('/login', reqData, {
                headers:  {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                }
            }
        )
```

Here is my nodejs code: -

```
app.post("/login", (req, res) => {
    const data = req.body;
    console.log("Data received: ", data);
    res.send("OK")
})
```

Every time I submit my form, I get undefined in my nodejs server.

Comment: What version of the express are you using? Can you add an index file?

Answer (score 0):

it might be possible because your body object isn't a valid json.
Try posting something like

```
const reqData = { 
   user: loginID, 
   pass: password 
}
```